# HD corruption - OS X partition now thinks it's FAT

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition

Well, I've got myself in a bit of a pickle here. I have been trying to do creative (unsupported, of course :^) things with my rMBP. I had been using multiple partitions successfully with OS X 10.9.5 and Boot Camp. I was finally going to upgrade to 10.10, but the installer didn't like my extra partitions, which means it wouldn't install a recovery partition, which I did want installed. So I began the process of removing the extra partitions, and things were going fine - until I removed an extra NTFS partition, rebooted, and—nothing. Wouldn't boot to either OS X or W7. Recovery partition wasn't available either. So I made a bootable OS X 10.9 flash drive and I boot from that. Disk Utility is now telling me it thinks my HFS+ OS X partition is FAT32. Oops! Attempting "Repair Disk" from Disk Utility doesn't help.

So, I'm looking for suggestions as to Next Steps. I am technically savvy, so I am willing to use the command line (very familiar with gdisk at this point, FBOW) if that's what it takes. I do have a TM backup of the OS X partition—but if I restore from that will I wipe out my Windows 7 NTFS partition as well? I have an old version of Drive Genius and I'm considering upgrading to see if that would help at all - but that's $50 I'd rather not pay (but would if it will keep me from reinstalling everything). I tried booting GPartEd but it reports "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system". Thanks for any suggestions here!

Comment: Do you have a recovery partition anywhere? On your Time Machine backup drive perhaps? (That'd only exist on directly connected drive, not Time Capsule or NAS)

Comment: Restoring OS X from time machine will not delete your windows partition (if everything works as expected) since it works on a file-basis. But you definitively want to create a backup of windows first.